# Loading high number of images to memory and save pickle

Tags: python, image, numpy, loading

I have a problem...

I have a dataset with 1200 cases and 30 classes per case and 160 images per class. These images are grayscale ndarrays, float64 dtype.

I would like to slice each case and get only 30 images from each class and put them in a dictionary where the first_key is case_name and second_one name of a class. After all of this I would like to save whole dictionary to a pickle.

but I run out of memory all the time.

```
brain_all = []

for dir in path.iterdir():
    brain_sample = {}
    path_dir = path_save / dir.name
    try:
        path_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=False)
    except FileExistsErorr:
        print('Folder is already there')
    for file in dir.iterdir():
        
        sample = nib.load(file).get_fdata()[:, :, 75:105]
        if 'flair' in file.name:
            brain_sample['flair'] = sample
        elif 't1ce' in file.name:
            brain_sample['t1ce'] = sample
    brain_all.append([file, brain_sample])
```

Comment: Options: 1) use a server with terabytes of RAM. 2) process your data in small chunks.

Comment: One of the issues with Python is that a slice like `[:, :, 75:105]` is a reference, and not a copy (it hard to tell from your code but it could be that all data `[:, :, :]` is kept in memory).  Try: `data = nib.load(file).get_fdata()` and `sample = data[:, :, 75:105].copy()`. After that try forcing memory release: `del data` and `gc.collect()`. Note: You forgot to tell us the resolution of your images.